# Cantor set cannot be expressed as a sum

Tags: real-analysis

[image: Question]

---

**Can somebody help with with (2)**

My solution for (1): Cantor set is defined as $C=\cap_n C_n$ where $C_{n+1}$ is obtained from $C_n$ by dropping 'middle third' of each closed interval in $C_n$

Cantor set is bounded by definition in region [0,1]

Since each $C_n$ is closed and $C$ is an intersection of such sets, $C$ is closed (arbitrary intersection of closed sets is a closed set).

As $C$ is closed and bounded, it is compact by Heine-Borel theorem.

Comment: Do you know that $C$ is nowhere dense, or are you asking for help for that precise part?

Comment: By the way, your solution for $(1)$ seems okay.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_n := a_n + C$. Then, $x$ is of the form $a_n + c$ with $c \in C$ for some $a_n$ if and only if $x \in A_n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. That is,

$$
\{x \in \mathbb{R} : x = c+a_n, n\in\mathbb{N}, c \in C\} = \bigcup_{n \geq1}A_n
$$

Our task is thus to show that $A := \bigcup_{n \geq 1} A_n \neq \mathbb{R}$. Now, we know that $C$ is compact and of empty interior. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the traslation

$$
f_n : y \in \mathbb{R} \mapsto y + a_n \in \mathbb{R}
$$

is a homeomorphism, and so $A_n = a_n + C = f_n(C)$ is compact and of empty interior. In particular, compact sets are closed in the reals, so $A$ is a union of closed sets of empty interior. By Baire's category theorem, $A$ has to have empty interior and thus $A \neq \mathbb{R}$.